# How to convert numpy datetime into the format "MM-DD"

Tags: python, date, matplotlib, charts, type-conversion

I created an arrange to label a chart that contains an observation for each day of 2013:

```
dates=np.arange('2013-01-01', '2014-01-01', dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

It worked, but, considering that all observations are from the same year (2013) I would like that the label was presented in MM-DD format. How can I convert it?
The image shows the chart and I would like that each label was in MM-DD format:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does it:

```
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(observation_dates, dfmax.Data_Value) 
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%m-%d"))
```

Comment: I plotted with this code: plt.figure('data')  
plt.plot(observation_dates, dfmax.Data_Value)
plt.show()
How can I add your code?

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Got this error message: 'list' object has no attribute 'xaxis'

Comment: Sorry, I think I messed up, try this one

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the [matplotlib date formatter](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter)

```
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
plt.figure('data')
plt.plot(dates) # After you plotted your data you can set the formatter
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%m-%d")) # plt.gca() gets the     current axes
plt.show()
```